# Recycler View add On Item Click Listener starting activity multiple times

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    try {
        Timeline timeline = dataSnapshot.getValue(Timeline.class);
        timelineArrayList.add(timeline);
        adapter= new TimelineAdapter(timelineArrayList);
        timelineRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        timelineRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notify();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.print(ex.toString());
    }

    timelineRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ImageViewer.class);
            intent.putExtra("img", timelineArrayList.get(position).getPhoto());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }));
```

addOnItemTouchListener starting activity multiple times what should i do. I tired by adding flags, by finishing activity once clicked.

Comment: why arent you using custom item selected listener or onclick listener from adapter class in view holder class?

Comment: use click listener from holder class, bad design btw

Comment: use interface between adapter and activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing worked for me so i decided to use list view and `listview.onItemClickListner()`
it worked for me. Thank you everyone

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#summary

Answer (score 0):

Use OnClickListener instead of addOnItemTouchListener

RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener is meant to be used when you want to detect a touch to an item while the list is scrolling, not for regular or direct touches

Answer (score 0):

An OnItemTouchListener functions a bit differently than the normal OnItemClickListener. Using the OnItemTouchListener, it is possible to allow the application to intercept touch events from the View hierarchy. What this basically means is that you can implement various forms of gesture manipulation like swipe straight into the Views of your RecyclerView.

> **When should you use it?**
>
> An OnItemClickListener should be used when you
>   need to determine what happens when the user clicks on a View in your
>   RecyclerView. This could be deleting something or starting up a new
>   activity. The OnItemTouchListener Is generally used to create gestural
>   interactivity to certain Views in your RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide onClickListener from ViewHolder to UI(Activity/Fragment) with use of Interface pattern and then start activity

Answer (score 0):

Please Add a OnclickListener to a view in your View Holder It will Work

**Here is An example**

```html
 public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        
        Button add;
       
        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            
            add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
           
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  
                }
            });
          
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Onclick listener

Comment: onclick listnere triggered on layout click

Comment: he want it to on item click